# Custom SPA Page Model Error - cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: model, single-page-application, aem

I am using AEM 6.5.11 and need to extend the SPA Page Model and form the project-specific Page model and add more properties to it such as analytics-related properties (which I will pick up from OSGi Config from this Model). Whether I use editable template design properties or I use OSGi configuration, I realized I need a model which will give me payload language, path, analytics URL, page 1 level up, and so on. So I wanted to implement this custom model to have control over what I needed to render on-page.

We are using Angular SPA and this is placed under customheaderlibs.html of the spa page component.

```html
<sly data-sly-use.mypage="com.sample.core.models.BasePageModel" />
${mypage.analyticsUrl}
```

Please note - The original Page inclusion on this header html worked fine-

```html
<meta
    property="cq:pagemodel_root_url"
    content="${page.hierarchyRootJsonExportUrl}"
    data-sly-use.page="com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.models.Page"/>
```

I created my page model by extending com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.internal.impl.PageImpl and implementing Page. WCM Core Components, spa.project.core 1.3.10 and uber-jar 6.5.11 are all there as dependencies on my core pom.xml.

The bundle looks to be in an **Installed** state now due to unresolved imported packages -
**com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.internal.impl -- Cannot be resolved**
If I do not extend the PageImpl and just implement AEM SPA Page interface, then the bundle is **Active** but my custom Page Model does not get resolved and page doesn't load. I also tried removing inclusion of com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.internal.impl paackage in core/pom.xml where in imported-packages I mentioned - `!com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.internal.impl`
The sample.core bundle went Active, but that looked like not the real solution. Page did not load and my custom Model still did not work during runtime.

```html
Cannot get DefaultSlingScript: Compilation errors in org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/apps/sample/components/page/customheaderlibs__002e__html.java: Line 61, column 2865 : com.sample.aem.core.models.BasePageModel cannot be resolved to a type
```

This is how I have declared my Custom SPA Page Model class

```html
import com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.internal.impl.PageImpl;
import com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.models.Page;

@Model(
        adaptables = {SlingHttpServletRequest.class, Resource.class},
        adapters = {Page.class, ContainerExporter.class},
        resourceType = BasePageModel.RESOURCE_TYPE,
        defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL
)
@Exporter(
        name = ExporterConstants.SLING_MODEL_EXPORTER_NAME,
        extensions = ExporterConstants.SLING_MODEL_EXTENSION
)
public class BasePageModel extends PageImpl implements Page {
  
    protected static final String RESOURCE_TYPE = "sample/components/page";
  
    @Self
    private SlingHttpServletRequest request;

    @ScriptVariable
    @JsonIgnore
    private Resource resource;
    
    @ScriptVariable
    @JsonIgnore
    protected ResourceResolver resolver;

    @ScriptVariable
    protected com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page currentPage;

    @ScriptVariable
    protected Style currentStyle;
    
    private String analyticsUrl = "CUSTOM ANALYTICS URL";
    
    @Nullable
    public String getAnalyticsUrl() {
        return analyticsUrl;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace as below -

```html
27.02.2022 13:14:44.395 *ERROR* [qtp1124137324-2030] org.apache.felix.http.jetty Bundles: Cannot start (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve afbr.core [642](R 642.5): missing requirement [afbr.core [642](R 642.5)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.internal.impl) Unresolved requirements: [[sample.core [642](R 642.5)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.internal.impl)])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve sample.core [642](R 642.5): missing requirement [sample.core [642](R 642.5)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.internal.impl) Unresolved requirements: [[sample.core [642](R 642.5)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.internal.impl)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2281)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:984)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BundlesServlet.doPost(BundlesServlet.java:365) [org.apache.felix.webconsole:4.6.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:611) [org.apache.felix.webconsole:4.6.2]
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager$3.run(OsgiManager.java:513) [org.apache.felix.webconsole:4.6.2]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:508) [org.apache.felix.webconsole:4.6.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:123) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:86) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at com.adobe.granite.cors.impl.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:88) [com.adobe.granite.cors:1.0.10.CQ650-B0002]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308) [com.adobe.granite.license:1.2.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:131) [org.apache.sling.i18n:2.5.14]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher$1.doFilter(Dispatcher.java:146) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1002) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at com.adobe.granite.cors.impl.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:88) [com.adobe.granite.cors:1.0.10.CQ650-B0002]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:137) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at com.adobe.granite.auth.oauth.impl.OAuthCallbackFilter.doFilter(OAuthCallbackFilter.java:69) [com.adobe.granite.auth.oauth:1.7.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:137) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at com.adobe.granite.auth.ims.impl.IMSClusterExchangeTokenPreprocessor.doFilter(IMSClusterExchangeTokenPreprocessor.java:281) [com.adobe.granite.auth.ims:1.3.12.CQ650-B0014]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:137) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:326) [org.apache.sling.security:1.1.16]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:137) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:97) [org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter:1.2.6]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:137) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager.invokePreprocessors(WhiteboardManager.java:1012) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:91) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:49) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.1.10]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: You can't extend PageImpl since impl package is not exported. You could inject com.adobe.aem.spa.project.core.models.Page using the delegate pattern

Comment: I started off with a simple model without extending PageImpl or without implementing Page.class. I bound the Model to project page resource type but it never got resolved
@Model(
  adaptables = {SlingHttpServletRequest.class, Resource.class},
  adapters = {ComponentExporter.class},
  resourceType = "sample/components/page",
  defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL
)
Bundle stayed Active, but on the page customheaderlibs.html. this never worked on page load -
<sly data-sly-use.basepage="com.ibm.core.models.BasepageModel" />
TRY PRINTING :  ${basepage.analyticsUrl}

Comment: A simple model should work if you only directly print something in HTML (not related to SPA). For testing purposes, I would remove adapters and resource type. 

Since you will need the same info in model.json, start adding additional annotations props one by one. E.g first resource type, then adapters, then inject SPA page...

Answer (score 1):

I could find the issue in my case - wanted to put it down for sharing.
I needed to export models on core/pom.xml.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
    <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
          <execution>
          <id>bnd-process</id>
          <goals>
             <goal>bnd-process</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <bnd><![CDATA[
             Sling-Model-Packages: com.sample.core.models
             Import-Package: javax.annotation;version=0.0.0,*
             Export-Package: com.sample.core.models,*
             Embed-Dependency: *;scope=compile|runtime
             Embed-StripGroup: true
             Embed-Transitive: true
             ]]></bnd>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).